# asp.net mvc Cookies múltiples

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, cookies

¿Cómo puedo crear una cookie con una colección de llave y valor?, ¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Ya que tengo lo siguiente pero no me funciona, sólo me aparece una cookie que es la primera pero no la segunda.

```
public static void SetCookie(string value1, int value2)
    {
        HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie("MICOOKIE");
        httpCookie.Domain = "localhost";
        httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        httpCookie.Values["cook1"] = value1;
        httpCookie.Values["cook2"] = value2.ToString();
        httpCookie.HttpOnly = true;
        httpCookie.Secure = false;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lo mejor [esto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178194.aspx) te sirve:

```
Response.Cookies["MICOOKIE"]["cook1"] = value1;
Response.Cookies["MICOOKIE"]["cook2"] = value2.ToString();
Response.Cookies["MICOOKIE"].Domain = "localhost";
Response.Cookies["MICOOKIE"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
Response.Cookies["MICOOKIE"].HttpOnly = true;
Response.Cookies["MICOOKIE"].Secure = false;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero ya había encontrado el problema con el código anterior, de igual forma probare este que me dejas para ver si igual me funciona. Saludos.